# Error in running firebase in app messaging in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am getting following error when adding firebase in app messaging library     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.0'
and      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.0'

Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/OkHttpDownloader;
    at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.injection.modules.PicassoModule.providesFiamController(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.0:52)
    at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.injection.modules.PicassoModule_ProvidesFiamControllerFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.0:34)
    at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.injection.modules.PicassoModule_ProvidesFiamControllerFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.0:11)
    at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
    at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.FiamImageLoader_Factory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.0:21)
    at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.FiamImageLoader_Factory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.0:8)...
```

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project again.

Comment: No, clean and rebuild doesnt work i tried.

Comment: Did you add OKHTTP library in your project--->  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'

Comment: This is still happening in `firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my error 
mistake was I was using Picasso library with in app messaging which was clashing so just comment out the Picasso library and run . It works.

Comment: I'm not explicitly using Picasso anywhere and I still get this error.